# How high to build a dam in Amsterdam in order that the probability of a flooding within the next 100 years be less than 1%?

Tags: st.statistics, free-probability

In the preface of the monography, Pr. D. Voiculescu Wrote:

> "Free probability and operator algebras The well-known question about how high to build a dam in Amsterdam in order that the probability of a flooding within the next $100$ years be less than $1\%$ based on the data on flooding for a certain number of years, is answered using max-stable laws. One may wonder whether there is a free analog to this application. What is a free dam in free Amsterdam to avoid a free flooding with free probability . . . ?"

As Voiculescu has not indicated any paper about the classical problem, I have made some researchs in order to have some references that are relatives to this subject. But in vain, I havn't found any document. 
What are the references about this subject?

Comment: this will likely be closed because it's not really about math, but a reference could be [A probabilistic approach of flood risk reduction in the Dutch Delta](https://www.hkv.nl/upload/publication/Adaptation_with_small_steps_or_a_big_step_TB_MK.pdf) [this is for the region below Rotterdam, but I presume the reference to Amsterdam should not be taken literally].